# Sql Server Disk I/O Troughput In Performance monitor

Tags: performance-tuning, sql-server-2019, trace-flags

i use sql server 2019 and trace flag 1117(Grow All Files in a FileGroup Equally) is on in my DataBase.
I need to consider the correct number of data files for primary file group according to my system resources. To do this, I need to check this operation with performance monitor software. But I do not know which counters I should use (for example writing on a disk per second)

First Test :

```sql
CREATE DATABASE TestIO
ON PRIMARY 
    ( NAME = N'PRIMARY1',            FILENAME = N'D:\DB\Temp\TestIO_PRIMARY1.mdf',FILEGROWTH=512GB,MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED,SIZE=2GB),
 FILEGROUP FG2 
    ( NAME = N'secondary',          FILENAME = N'D:\DB\Temp\TestIO_secondary.ndf',FILEGROWTH=512GB,MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED,SIZE=2GB)
 LOG ON 
    ( NAME = N'TestIO_log',     FILENAME = N'D:\DB\Temp\TEST_log.ldf' ,FILEGROWTH=2GB,MAXSIZE=2TB,SIZE=2GB)
GO
```

Seccond Test :

```sql
USE master
GO
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS TestIO
CREATE DATABASE TestIO
ON PRIMARY 
    ( NAME = N'PRIMARY1',            FILENAME = N'D:\DB\Temp\TestIO_PRIMARY1.mdf',FILEGROWTH=512GB,MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED,SIZE=2GB),
    ( NAME = N'PRIMARY2',            FILENAME = N'D:\DB\Temp\TestIO_PRIMARY2.mdf',FILEGROWTH=512GB,MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED,SIZE=2GB), 
    ( NAME = N'PRIMARY3',            FILENAME = N'D:\DB\Temp\TestIO_PRIMARY3.mdf',FILEGROWTH=512GB,MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED,SIZE=2GB), 
    ( NAME = N'PRIMARY4',            FILENAME = N'D:\DB\Temp\TestIO_PRIMARY4.mdf',FILEGROWTH=512GB,MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED,SIZE=2GB), 
 FILEGROUP FG2 
    ( NAME = N'secondary',          FILENAME = N'D:\DB\Temp\TestIO_secondary.ndf',FILEGROWTH=512GB,MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED,SIZE=2GB)
 LOG ON 
    ( NAME = N'TestIO_log',     FILENAME = N'D:\DB\Temp\TEST_log.ldf' ,FILEGROWTH=2GB,MAXSIZE=2TB,SIZE=2GB)
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to consider the correct number of data files for primary file group according to my system resources.

It's 1.  Splitting a filegroup across multiple files on the same disk has no performance benefit.

This is not the case with TempDb, but the reasons are specific to supporting high-frequency table creation and deletion. See [Recommendations to reduce allocation contention in SQL Server tempdb database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/recommendations-reduce-allocation-contention).

Generally IO is no faster when split across multiple files, and so there's no "best practice" to use multiple files for databases other than TempDb.

It's not a bad practice to create your filegroup with 2,4, or 6 files, especially if your database will be large.  But the benefit is not performance:  it's the ability to restore on servers with different drive configurations, or to eventually split the database files across disks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use which i generally do when trying to measure overall latency at file level if spanned across multiple or same drive. You will find it under FirstResponderKit [sp_BlitzFirst](https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/). As mentioned on docs *it Looks at Perfmon counters for CPU use, slow drive response times, or low Page Life Expectancy*

Try experimenting with some parameters to get additional data if needed as mentioned :-

> @ExpertMode = 1 – doesn’t do more in-depth checks, but DOES return a whole lot more data, including sections on wait stats, file stats, and Perfmon counters. Calls sp_BlitzWho at the start & end too so you can see which queries were running at those times. @SinceStartup = 1 – displays wait stats, file stats, and Perfmon counters since the SQL Server started up. @Seconds = 5 – by default, we take a 5-second sample of activity, but you can take a longer sample if you want to run a load test or demo.

Moreover you can collect the data historically to give you more accurate analysis over time by logging data into table. Again it will have more than what you asked from perfmon counters but you can always tailor around it to customize as needed.